# Common heade & footer in all webpages without using PHP, JSP, ASP

Tags: javascript, jquery, include-path

I have header and footer separate html files. I need to include those files in many number of webpages, I am looking for a solution with the help of using Javascript and jQuery.
But not using PHP, ASP & JSP technologies.

Comment: show your code in question

Answer (score 1):

You can use [w3-include-html](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_html_include_1) to include html file into html file.

See example : **[W3school](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_html_include_1)**

---

Also use [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method of jquery

See : **[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988855/include-another-html-file-in-a-html-file)** already solved

Comment: @Vinay, is this useful?

Answer (score 0):

If your server supports it, you can use SSI.
[Apache httpd SSI](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/ssi.html)